# javascript pass XML document object as argument

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp

I am reading an XML document to dynamically populate select boxes.
The first select box is populated with all the activity names which i have done already in jsp.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("C:\\Projects\\RegressionTester\\src\\main\\resources\\TestActivitiesXML.xml");
NodeList activityNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("activity");
```

Upon selecting an activity the next select box should be populated with the activity's functions. I am trying to accomplish through a javascript method using the onchange eventhandler. But I have trouble passing the doc object as an argument. Any help would be appreciated.

```
onchange="return testMethodChange(this,<%=doc%>)"
```

Comment: xml as follows: 
<activities>
 <activity>
  <name>activity1</name>
  <functions> 
   <function>function1</function> 
  </functions>
 </activity>
 <activity>
  <name>activity2</name>
  <functions> 
   <function>function1</function>
   <function>function2</function>  
  </functions>
 </activity>
</activities>

Answer (score 0):

- If you pass like this **testMethodChange(this,<%=doc%>)**. It will not work because **testMethodChange** will only get some text.
- Instead read and parse **TestActivitiesXML.xml** in javascript function itself.
- After parsing the XML populate it in drop down according to your requirement.